# What php code do I need to get text from wordpress text widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am adding some additional logic to page.php in a wordpress theme.
This theme already has 4 sidebar widgets (north, south, east, west).

I need to get the text that is entered into a text widget from the wp-admin widget panel within my page.php code.  This logic is "outside the wordpress loop".

Answer (score 0):

if I have you understood correct...

You may display text from text widget only in sidebar, so you have to call a sidebar logic in your file `page.php` and then add the text widget to this new sidebar.